# couldn't install mdb-react-ui-kit

Tags: reactjs, mdbreact

> $ sudo npm i mdb-react-ui-kit
>
> added 17 packages, and audited 18 packages in 3s
>
> 1 package is looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities
> [rajkumar@Endeavour website]$ npm run start
>
> > start
> > docusaurus-start
>
> LiveReload server started on port 35729
> Docusaurus server started on port 3000
> Error: Cannot find module 'mdb-react-ui-kit'
> Require stack:
>
> - /home/rajkumar/Coding/docusaur/survivejs-demo/website/core/Footer.js
> - /home/rajkumar/Coding/docusaur/survivejs-demo/website/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/core/Site.js
> - /home/rajkumar/Coding/docusaur/survivejs-demo/website/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/server/server.js
> - /home/rajkumar/Coding/docusaur/survivejs-demo/website/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/server/start.js
> - /home/rajkumar/Coding/docusaur/survivejs-demo/website/node_modules/docusaurus/lib/start-server.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>   at Object. (/home/rajkumar/Coding/docusaur/survivejs-demo/website/core/Footer.js:2:1)
>   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
>   at Module._compile (/home/rajkumar/Coding/docusaur/survivejs-demo/website/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:136:24)
>   at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
>   at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/rajkumar/Coding/docusaur/survivejs-demo/website/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:141:7)
>   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>   ^C
>   [rajkumar@Endeavour website]$ sudo npm i mdb-react-ui-kit
>   npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
>   npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
>   npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
>   npm ERR! node_modules/react
>   npm ERR!   peer react@">=0.14.0" from @hypnosphi/create-react-context@0.3.1
>   npm ERR!   node_modules/@hypnosphi/create-react-context
>   npm ERR!     @hypnosphi/create-react-context@"^0.3.1" from react-popper@1.3.11
>   npm ERR!     node_modules/react-popper
>   npm ERR!       react-popper@"^1.3.7" from mdbreact@5.2.0
>   npm ERR!       node_modules/mdbreact
>   npm ERR!         mdbreact@"^5.2.0" from the root project
>   npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.3.0" from @material-ui/core@3.9.3
>   npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
>   npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^3.2.0" from material-ui-pickers@2.2.4
>   npm ERR!     node_modules/material-ui-pickers
>   npm ERR!       material-ui-pickers@"2.2.4" from mdbreact@5.2.0
>   npm ERR!       node_modules/mdbreact
>   npm ERR!         mdbreact@"^5.2.0" from the root project
>   npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"3.9.3" from mdbreact@5.2.0
>   npm ERR!     node_modules/mdbreact
>   npm ERR!       mdbreact@"^5.2.0" from the root project
>   npm ERR!   26 more (react-transition-group, @material-ui/system, ...)
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
>   npm ERR! mdb-react-ui-kit@"*" from the root project
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
>   npm ERR! node_modules/react
>   npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from mdb-react-ui-kit@3.0.0
>   npm ERR!   node_modules/mdb-react-ui-kit
>   npm ERR!     mdb-react-ui-kit@"*" from the root project
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
>   npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
>   npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-08T01_20_39_248Z-debug-0.log

Looks like this is due to reactjs version conflict but not sure how to fix this error?